# Can't perform credit card formatting in angular reactive form while extending a class from another class

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

**Having problems while extending a class from another to validate a particular field of credit card number**

I want to show my card format as 0000-0000-0000-0000

I have used a regex pattern from the internet but its not working.

***CardNumberControl class file***

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms'

export class CardNumberControl extends FormControl {
    setValue(value: string, options: any) {
        if (value.match(/^(?:4[0-9]{4}(?:[0-9]{1})?)$/)) {
            super.setValue(this.value + "-", { ...options, emitModelToViewChange: true });
            return;
        }
    super.setValue(value, { ...options, emitModelToViewChange: true });
}

}
```

***Parent class file- CardForm class file***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms'
import { DateFormControl } from '../date-form-control'
import { CardNumberControl } from '../card-number-control'
import { $ } from 'protractor';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card-form',
  templateUrl: './card-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card-form.component.css']
})
export class CardFormComponent implements OnInit {

cardForm = new FormGroup({
name: new FormControl('',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]),
cardNumber: new CardNumberControl('',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(16),Validators.maxLength(16), Validators.pattern(/[3-9]/)]),
Expiration: new DateFormControl('',[Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/\d{2}$/)]),
securityNumber: new FormControl('',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3),Validators.maxLength(3)])

});

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  OnSubmit(){
    console.log("Form was Submitted");
    
  }
  OnReset(){
    this.cardForm.reset();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using Reactive Forms.

I have used `ngx-mask` https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask (Weekly Downloads
106,417) in my project to handle similar formats and it was perfectly fine.

It is a straightforward configuration and usage.

In Module:

```
import { IConfig, NgxMaskModule } from "ngx-mask";

....
import { IConfig, NgxMaskModule } from "ngx-mask";
....

const NGX_LOADING_CONFIG = new NgxLoadingConfiguration();
export const NGX_MASK_OPTIONS: Partial<IConfig> = {
  thousandSeparator: ",",
};


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    NgxMaskModule.forRoot(NGX_MASK_OPTIONS),
  ],
  exports: [...],
  providers: [
    ....
  ],
})
export class AdminModule {}
```

While in the component, simply

```
<label for="code">Code</label>
<input
  id="code"
  type="text"
  class="form-control"
  formControlName="code"
  placeholder="00-00-00"
  mask="00-00-00"
/>
```

Sure, in your case the mask is `0000-0000-0000-0000`

Maybe I missing code as I did use it some time ago but the documentation of the package already very clear and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [@rxweb/reactive-form-validators](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rxweb/reactive-form-validators) which provides an inbuilt validation to perform validation on the creditCard number fields

In the below example the `creditCardNumber` field is been validated based upon the cardType selected from the `creditCardTypes` array, based upon the selected value it will validate accordingly

below is the component code :

```js
 export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  userFormGroup: FormGroup;

  creditCardTypes = [
    "Visa",
    "AmericanExpress",
    "Maestro",
    "JCB",
    "Discover",
    "DinersClub",
    "MasterCard"
  ];

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      cardType: [""],
      creditCardNumber: [
        "",
        RxwebValidators.creditCard({ fieldName: "cardType" })
      ]
    });
  }
}
```

The component html code

```html
<div>
  <form  [formGroup]="userFormGroup">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Card Type</label>
      <select formControlName="cardType" class="form-control">
        <option [value]="item" *ngFor="let item of creditCardTypes">{{item}}</option>
      </select>
      <small class="form-text text-muted">Based on selection of card type conditional validation is applied<br/></small>
     <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="userFormGroup.controls.cardType.errors">{{userFormGroup.controls.cardType.errors.creditCard.message}}<br/></small> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Credit Card No.</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="creditCardNumber" class="form-control"  />
      <small class="form-text text-muted">Enter Selected Card's Card No<br/></small>
    <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="userFormGroup.controls.creditCardNumber.errors">{{userFormGroup.controls.creditCardNumber.errors.creditCard.message}}<br/></small>
    </div>
    <button [disabled]="!userFormGroup.valid" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is the complete [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6iyxdj-vhqy7e?file=src/app/credit-card-add.component.ts) example